# Mach-O header code: 0x72613c21 when importing Microsoft Azure Mobile Framework

Tags: azure, swift3, xcode8

I'm running Swift 3.0 on Xcode 8.0 beta 2 on my MBP and I'm currently trying to integrate my application to Azure's server. I'm currently just trying to get the Swift 3.0 version of the example code to work. Currently I've just started the project and all I have is a `ProjectName-Bridging-Header.h`and a Frameworks folder with the Framework imported and linked as shown here:

[image]

this in itself already produces errors as shown here:
[image]

I have already tried:

- Disabling Bitcode
- Deleting Files located in ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
- Starting the project again
- Cleaning and Rebuilding multiple times
- Restarting Xcode
- Re-downloading the framework
- Reinstalling the framework and respective files multiple times.

Note: This seems to work seamlessly on Xcode7.3 with Swift 2.3 (I believe it's 2.3...)

Might it just be that I now must wait until Microsoft updates their API? This same error also persists for AWS (Amazon Web Services).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to [Azure's GitHub repo for iOS](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-services). Clone the repository, open it.

Open the folder `sdk`, open the folder `iOS`, then open the `Xcode` project named `WindowsAzureMobileServices.xcodeproject`. This project contains all classes that are required for the `framework` you mentioned.

Now close the project come back to `src` folder, and select all files except `info.plist` and `.DS_Store`. And drag all those files to your `Xcode` project, If you are on a very new project, `Xcode` will help you with creating a `Bridging-Header`.

Now you have added all the files, and created a `Bridging-Header`, now `import` all `classes` in `Bridging-Header`, like below.

```
#import "MSClient.h"
#import "MSCoreDataStore.h"
#import "MSDateOffset.h"
#import "MSError.h"
#import "MSFilter.h"
#import "MSLoginController.h"
#import "MSPullSettings.h"
#import "MSPush.h"
#import "MSQuery.h"
#import "MSQueryResult.h"
#import "MSSyncContext.h"
#import "MSSyncContextReadResult.h"
#import "MSSyncTable.h"
#import "MSTable.h"
#import "MSTableOperation.h"
#import "MSTableOperationError.h"
#import "MSUser.h"
```

Now build and run the project, there will be no error. You can access these `classes` in your `Swift` file very easily like this.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let client = MSClient()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'd also just like to put this out there for the method that you've mentioned just in case anyone else needs this help - to copy and paste the files, I did this http://osxdaily.com/2012/10/11/save-list-of-files-folder-contents-as-text/